# How to vertically fix navigation arrows?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a modal album which shows images with different sizes. My pbolem is that how to style the navigation arrows, so that they appear at the middle of the page, no matter what is the size of the image. Here is my code:

```
<div class="row img-box">
    <div class="col-1">
        <span @click="nextImg(-1)"  class="nav-arrow">&#10094;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <h1>Modal comes here</h1>
        <img class="img-fluid modal-img" :src=" getImgUrl(currentMediaUrl)">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <span @click="nextImg(1)" class="nav-arrow">&#10095;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant css:

```
.modal-img {
  max-height: 1080px;
}

.img-box {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
}
.nav-arrow {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

But whatever I tweak the CSS can not get the desired effect. Hence the question.

Comment: is this what u are looking for? `http://jsfiddle.net/vcw701Ld/`

Comment: Well, basically yes. But the arrows still jump up and down, depending the size of image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vcw701Ld/2/ this might work better, but you'll need to change the css to what u want. because the buttons are now at a `top: 25%;` and this can be tweaked to anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position `fixed`

```css
.modal-img {
  max-height: 1080px;
}

.img-box {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content: center;
}
.nav-arrow {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: fixed;
   top: 120px;  
}
.nav-left {   
  left: 10px; 
}
.nav-right { 
    right: 10px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="row img-box">
    <div class="col-1">
        <span @click="nextImg(-1)"  class="nav-arrow nav-left">&#10094;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <h1>Modal comes here</h1>
        <img class="img-fluid modal-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500C/O https://placeholder.com/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <span @click="nextImg(1)" class="nav-arrow nav-right">&#10095;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: navs still jump when the image size change.

Comment: If the image height is more body will scroll, so that arrow will jump. So instead of percentage(%) value keep px

//Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply `transform: translateY(-50%)` on arrow container's, in order to put the arrows in the center.

```
.nav-arrow {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

or simply, remove `position: absolute; top: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you? I have added the bootstrap class `align-items-center` and some padding to spans

```css
.modal-img {
  max-height: 1080px;
}


.nav-arrow {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        
<div class="row img-box align-items-center">
    <div class="col-1 ">
        <span @click="nextImg(-1)"  class="nav-arrow pt-5 d-inline-block">&#10094;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 text-center">
    <h1>Modal comes here</h1>
        <img class="img-fluid modal-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/O https://placeholder.com/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <span @click="nextImg(1)" class="nav-arrow pt-5 d-inline-block">&#10095;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```